# node.js / sqlite - Serializing callbacks as well as the main functions

Tags: javascript, node.js, serialization, sqlite

Example:

Database table with 2 rows:

```
 rowid name qty date   
 1     milk   3 8/25    
 2     milk  40 8/30
```

An inventory transaction to subtract 5 milk items needs to be executed using the oldest milk first.

e.g.

Select rowid 1
wait for its callback and in it Delete rowid 1 as its qty goes to 0 and is therefore spent

New deletion qty = 5 - 3 = 2. Since its not 0, another Select needs to be made.

Select rowid 2

wait for its callback and in it Update rowid 2 to set qty = 38.

The serialize capability in the sqlite binding will only serialize the two Selects. There's no way to know the second Select is even needed until the first Select and its callback are finished. It's only then that its realized that the first Select offered an insufficient qty.

How does one serialize the first Select and its callback using pure JavaScript - no JQuery or other libraries.

Here's a pseudo code example:
This is the smallest example I can think of to demo the issue.

Assume db is the result of a sqlite database open call which was successful.

```
var deletionQty = 5;

function selectCallBack(error, row) {
   // Assume no error.
   if (deletionQty >= row.qty) {
      // Delete row.rowNum
      deletionQty -= row.qty;   // Need to get the next table row to deduct remaining inventory from it.
   } else {
      // Update row.rowNum -> set qty = qty - deletionQty
      deletionQty = 0;          // Done!
   }
}

while (deletionQty > 0) {
   db.get("SELECT rowid AS rowNum, qty FROM Inventory ORDER BY date LIMIT 1", selectCallBack);
}
```

The problem is that the while will execute continuously because nothing within its scope changes the value of deletionQty.
Only the callback modifies it and since these are async events, the while loop will execute, say 100 times before the
callback changes the value of deletionQty. If there were a 1 to 1 relationship (a synchronous relationship) so that only
one db.get is executed and then its callback is executed before the next while loop cycle, everything would work fine.
It's the async delayed callback that allows the while to execute continuously setting up new callbacks that's the issue.

Comment: You're going to need to edit your question to include some of the code that you're struggling with. It's not clear what you're asking.

Comment: I'm not having a problem with code. The issue is how to turn off asynch so that a Select and its callback are executed as one logical thought BEFORE the next Select is even contemplated/attempted. Putting Selects in a loop spawns X number of callbacks and there is no synchronization between the select and its callback. In my example, the first callback MUST execute BEFORE the second Select and I know of no way to control that. That's what I'm looking for.

Comment: You can't turn off async for most functionality in Node. It's fundamental to Node. If you added your code (or some of it), it would be easier to show you. It sounds like you just want to put the second call inside the callback for the first. Further, I'm not sure why you're set on not using other libraries. There are more than a few that would make this pattern (if I'm understanding it correctly), quite easy.

Comment: I updated the question to try to highlight what I'm talking about.

Comment: Why not trigger the next delete after the previous one has completed?

Comment: The credit is @WiredPrairie's, but just to be explicit: in `SelectCallBack()`, right after `deletionQty -= row.qty;`, simply issue your `db.get("SELECT rowid...`). Then, at the very bottom, just lose the `while()` (but keep it's body: a one-time invocation of `db.get()`).

Comment: If I only had to access at most 2 rows, your suggestion would work. What if I need to SELECT and process 5 rows or 50 row or 500 rows to to bring down a deletionQty of, lets say, 5000. I need a loop to do as many selects as is necessary to do the job. The loop would issue the selects asynchronously and without knowing what the 1st select returned, its impossible to continue with the second select. If the 1st select returns qty=10000, then I only need that select. If its qty=100, then I know I need at least one more select, and so on and so on till the sum of the qtys per select = 5000.

Comment: WiredPrairie: Except for the trivial case, the task I'm trying to accomplish is impossible without synchronous database SELECT and the firing of the callback. I don't have an issue with Node's async always methodology. It's the binding to the sqlite database that I need to become synchronized. There's no way to do it asynchronously as it is impossible to know ahead of time how many SELECT's will be required in total, and the data from the very first SELECT determines if the second and subsequent are needed or not. The data returned from the SELECT's rules what happens next.

Answer (score 0):

I've recently created a simple abstraction named WaitFor to call async functions in sync mode (based on Fibers): https://github.com/luciotato/waitfor

your code with wait.for:

```
...in a fiber...
var deletionQty = 5;
while (deletionQty > 0) {
   var data= wait.forMethod(db,'get',"SELECT rowid AS rowNum, qty FROM Inventory ORDER BY date LIMIT 1");
   if (deletionQty >= data.qty) {
      // Delete row.rowNum
      wait.forMethod(db,'delete', data.id);
      deletionQty -= data.qty;   // Need to get the next table row to deduct remaining inventory from it.
   } else {
      // Update row.rowNum -> set qty = qty - deletionQty
      wait.forMethod(db,'update'...
      deletionQty = 0;          // Done!
   }

}//loop
```

WiredPrairie's comment it's the most accurate. You can't turn off async in Node. It's fundamental to Node. You need a lib like wait.for(based on node-fibers), or 'async' or promises (Q) to code sequential logic.

DB sequential logic it's not what's node is made for.

check this answer also:
[Callback hell in nodejs?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18095107/callback-hell-in-nodejs/18229477#18229477)

Beyond all this, maybe you need to have a table with: product_id, qyt_in_stock
and increment or decrement this field instead of deleting and inserting rows.

Comment: I don't want to turn off async in node. I want to turn off async in the binding to sqlite. I don't see how your code solves the problem. Where is my callback? the db.get needs a callback and its that callback that I want to sync with the db.get. I want the db.get to WAIT and fire the callback as soon as the result is ready, and when the callback ends, the next db.get in the loop is executed.

Comment: db.get is an async function. It will return immediatly, and will fire the callback ONLY when de data is ready.

Comment: Wait.for, creates a default callback for db.get, and then WAITS until the callback is called, and your data is ready. -- wait.for allows you to call an async function in sync mode,  so you can wait.for the results of the select and then decide to delete or update.

Comment: I'm going to study this "fiber" thing to see if I want to use it. I don't like to add in libraries unless absolutely necessary since many of them eventually die of neglect and then the code based on them has a problem. I see this issue really as a hole in node.js that should be filled somewhat "officially" by having node come up with a way to handle this or bless a solution to give it support so that it has a better chance of not dying of neglect. I'll revisit this when I'm done evaluating. Thanks for the heads up as I never heard of fiber before.