# Node.js event driven paradigm = messy code?

Tags: node.js, redis

I am coming from a PHP background and am now trying to get used to the event driven paradigm of Node.js. However, my code quickly get messy. Below I compare procedural code with actual Node.js Redis code. Am I doing this right?

PROCEDURAL (pseude code)

```
if(!client.get("user:name:koen")) {
    client.set("user:name:koen", "user:id:" + client.incr("count:users"));
}
```

EVENT DRIVEN (actual code)

```
client.get("user:name:koen", function(err, res) {
  if(!res){
    client.incr("count:users", function(err, count){ 
      client.set("user:name:koen", "user:id:" + count, function (err, res) {
        callback(err, res);
      });
    }); 
  }
});
```

Comment: Have a look at the Deferred concept of jQuery or similar libraries. It makes the code much more readable in my opinion.

Comment: You mean "synchronous vs asynchronous". Both are procedural. As for the main issue: yeah, this is how you do it in asynchronous paradigm. You can use some helpers (like [async.js](https://github.com/caolan/async)) but in the end it will look more or less like this.

Comment: Alright, that's all I needed to know. Just wanted to make sure I wasn't over complicating things. Thanks.

Comment: It's often referred to as [*callback hell*](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18095107/callback-hell-in-nodejs).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Callback hell, mentioned in the question, is greately explained here, as well as how to write the code to avoid it:

http://callbackhell.com/