# Using EventEmitter instead of callback?

Tags: javascript, node.js, events

I have a code which makes an `ajax` call, which has a `callback`. Is there a way i can replace the `callback` with an `event emitter`.

Below is my `code`.

```
 var _getPoll = function(params){
    var url = "http://localhost/poll"

    console.log(url);

    request({
        headers: {
            accept: 'application/json'
        },
        uri: url,
        method: 'GET'
    }, function(err, response, body){
        body = JSON.parse(body);
        console.log(body);
    })
}
```

Is it possible to replace the callback with an EventEmitter like below.

```
function(err, response, body){
    body = JSON.parse(body);
    console.log(body);
}
```

**Replace**

```
this.emit('jsonResponse', err, response, body);
```

Comment: I'm curious. What would be the benefit of not using a callback?

Comment: @KJPrice: Next callbacks are always pain... that's the reason...

Comment: I don't understand the question. The EventEmitter is a system that lets you assign a callback to fire when an event happens.

Comment: Related: [Callback hell in nodejs?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18095107/callback-hell-in-nodejs)

Comment: ...Given your example code at the bottom, you're still using a callback function. So why not give it a name, and use the named function? So you'd have `function foobar(err, response, body){`, and then just put `foobar` where the current anonymous function is. Or you can have `_getPoll` receive it as an argument or as one of the `params`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is there a way i can replace the callback with an event emitter.

Yes. In fact, [request](https://github.com/request/request) already *does* return you an event emitter. You'd listen to it instead of passing your callback directly into the `request()` call. It will emit a `complete` event with the body as soon as the response stream has ended.

```
 function _getPoll(params) {
    var url = "http://localhost/poll";

    console.log(url);

    request({
        headers: {
            accept: 'application/json'
        },
        uri: url,
        method: 'GET'
    }).on("complete", function(response, body) {
        console.log(JSON.parse(body));
    });
}
```

> Is it possible to replace the callback with `this.emit('jsonResponse', err, response, body)`

I'm not sure whether you mean the right thing here. No, you cannot replace the callback with anything but a different callback. You can not pass an even emitter object, and you can not pass the result of calling `this.emit('jsonResponse', err, response, body)` either. You might do something like

```
var e = new EventEmitter();
request({…}, function(err, response, body){
    if (err)
        e.emit("error", err)
    else
        e.emit('jsonResponse', response, JSON.parse(body));
})
```

> Next callbacks are always pain... that's the reason...

I think what you are actually looking for are [promises](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4296505/1048572). Of course, they're [still callbacks](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22562045/1048572) (just as event emitters are), but they are much more composable.